# Vertically center login form?

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using AngularJS and Ionic for building a hybrid mobile application.

This is my login form:

```
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <form class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" class="text-align-center" placeholder="{{ 'EMAIL' | translate }}" ng-model="credentials.email"  autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="password" class="text-align-center" placeholder="{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate }}" ng-model="credentials.password"  autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-block button-stable" type="submit" ng-click="login()">{{ 'LOGIN' | translate }}</button>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
```

What is a good way to make this login form vertically aligned?

Comment: See [How to vertically center a div for all browsers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers)

Comment: @iWörk: That doesn't work. It doesn't make any change to the appearence of my form. The form is still on the top of the page

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

For html

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="middle">
<div class="inner">
 <ion-content class="padding">
    <form class="list">
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="text" class="text-align-center" placeholder="{{ 'EMAIL' | translate }}" ng-model="credentials.email"  autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
        <input type="password" class="text-align-center" placeholder="{{ 'PASSWORD' | translate }}" ng-model="credentials.password"  autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off">
      </label>
      <button class="button button-block button-stable" type="submit" ng-click="login()">{{ 'LOGIN' | translate }}</button>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

For style CSS

```
<style>
.outer {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; 
    width: /*whatever width you want*/;
}
</style>
```

may be help you

Comment: Thanks for the attempt. That didn't affect the appearence of my login form. The login form is still on the top of the page after these changes.

Answer (score 0):

I tried several proposed css solution that I found, but many didn't work. I think it might have something to do with Ionics css.

This solution which is specifically for Ionic worked fo me:

http://play.ionic.io/app/6f5cda89e7fd

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <ion-pane>
      <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
        <h1 class="title">Awesome App</h1>
      </ion-header-bar>
      <ion-content class="padding loginForm">
        <div class="loginForm-wrapper">
          <label class="item item-input item-input-rounded">
            <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input item-input-rounded">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password">
          </label>
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-pane>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.loginForm .scroll {
  height: 100%;
}
  .loginForm .loginForm-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
```